# Docker error connecting to database - using nginx, mysql and virtual hosts for many other websites

Tags: mysql, wordpress, docker, nginx

I am new to Docker. I have overtaken another guys business and I need to exchange a running website content with a new one. The running content is a typo3 website and the new one is Wordpress based. The servers handles many different Websites with different urls managed by a nginx reverse proxy.

My problem: I cannot connect to the new database.
My compose file:

```
version: "2"

services:
#Database
   db:
     image: mysql
     volumes:
       - /srv/db/production/website/wordpress/current:/var/lib/mysql
     restart: always
     networks:
      - proxy-tier
      - post
     environment:
       MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
       MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress_website
       MYSQL_USER: wordpress_website
       MYSQL_PASSWORD: password

#Wordpress
   wordpress:
     depends_on:
       - db
     image: wordpress
     restart: always
     networks:
      - proxy-tier
      - post
     volumes:
       -  /srv/www/production/website/wordpress/current:/var/www/html
     environment:
      - VIRTUAL_HOST=website.com
      - VIRTUAL_NETWORK=nginx-proxy
      - VIRTUAL_PORT=80
      #- VIRTUAL_PORT=443
      - LETSENCRYPT_HOST=website.com
      - LETSENCRYPT_EMAIL=email@website.com
      - WORDPRESS_DB_USER=wordpress_website
      - WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD=password
      - WORDPRESS_DB_NAME=wordpress_website

networks:
  proxy-tier:
    external:
      name: nginxproxy_default
  post:
    external:
      name: mail_frontend
```

Info:

- the networks have been made prior to my work so I think they are
  working.
- I can perfectly connect to the new database within the terminal (it
  is just completely empty)
- The wp-config data is correct but the Host just says "mysql".
- I have checked with other working docker+mysql+wordpress files and
  they have the same host.
- I have tried to set different port like ports:- "3307:3306" but it
  did not help.

What am I doing wrong? I really need help because I am lost.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
$ docker-compose down
$ docker ps -a ##check that the containers are not running
```

Clean the volumes of the "db" and start again

If the containers are OK, you shuld try again to connect to a host port and see the DB from there.
In the container "db" ->

```
ports:
  - "3309:3306"
  - "portHOST:porContainer"
```

Bye.